# onLocationChanged not getting called in Gingerbread

Tags: android, gps, locationmanager, locationlistener

I have a mystery for you!  I can get the code below to work on my Samsung Galaxy test phone, which is running 2.2 (Froyo).  It doesn't work on my HTC Thunderbolt test phone, which is running 2.3.4 (Gingerbread).  This is about as simple as it gets when it comes to gathering location info, but I have also implemented the best practices explained [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/06/deep-dive-into-location.html) with the same results:  Froyo is go, Gingerbread is dead.

What are some things I should try in order to solve this problem?  Is it my code?  Is it hardware, software?  Permissions?  Have I angered the computer science gods?  I will accept the first answer given with a suggestion that leads to a solution.  Thanks for the help!

My Activity:

```
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.location.LocationProvider;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SimpleLocationProjectActivity extends Activity {

    private LocationManager mLocationManager;
    private MyLocationListener mLocationListener;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        mLocationListener = new MyLocationListener();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListener);
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.i("SIMPLE APP", "Starting location services.");
        List<String> providers = mLocationManager.getAllProviders();
        for (int i = 0 ; i < providers.size(); i++){
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(providers.get(i), 1, 1, mLocationListener);
        }

    }

    public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener{

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                Bundle extras) {
            String statusStr;
            switch (status){
            case LocationProvider.OUT_OF_SERVICE:
                statusStr = "Out of Service";
                break;
            case LocationProvider.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE:
                statusStr = "Temporarily unavailable";
                break;
            case LocationProvider.AVAILABLE:
                statusStr = "Available";
                break;
            default:
                statusStr = "Huhhh??";  
            }
            Log.i("SIMPLE APP", "Provider:  " + provider + "   Status is:  " + statusStr);


        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            Log.i("SIMPLE APP", "Provider:  " + provider + " is enabled.");
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            Log.i("SIMPLE APP", "Provider:  " + provider + " is disabled.");
        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            double latitute = location.getLatitude();
            double longitude = location.getLongitude();
            Toast.makeText(SimpleLocationProjectActivity.this, "Lat is " + latitute + "  and lng is " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            //This never gets called on my HTC Thunderbolt...
            Log.i("SIMPLE APP", "Provider:  " + location.getProvider() + "   Lat is " + latitute + "  and lng is " + longitude);
        }
    }
}
```

My Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0"
    package="com.silithcrowe.simplelocationproject" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"/>
    <application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".SimpleLocationProjectActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

EDIT:  Sample of logcat while it's running:

```
03-01 11:37:43.529: D/RPC(1662): read RPC packet
03-01 11:37:43.529: D/RPC(1662): read RPC packet size: [272]
03-01 11:37:43.529: V/locapi_rpc_glue(1662): Callback received: 4 (cb_id=0x67E0001 handle=2)
03-01 11:37:43.529: D/RPC(1662): written RPC packet size: [28]
03-01 11:37:43.529: D/RPC(1662): read RPC packet
03-01 11:37:43.529: D/RPC(1662): read RPC packet size: [272]
03-01 11:37:43.529: V/locapi_rpc_glue(1662): Callback received: 4 (cb_id=0x67E0001 handle=2)
03-01 11:37:43.529: D/RPC(1662): written RPC packet size: [28]
03-01 11:37:43.529: D/RPC(1662): read RPC packet
03-01 11:37:43.529: D/RPC(1662): read RPC packet size: [272]
03-01 11:37:43.529: V/locapi_rpc_glue(1662): Callback received: 4 (cb_id=0x67E0001 handle=2)
03-01 11:37:43.529: D/RPC(1662): written RPC packet size: [28]
03-01 11:37:43.529: D/RPC(1662): read RPC packet
03-01 11:37:43.529: D/RPC(1662): read RPC packet size: [96]
03-01 11:37:43.529: V/locapi_rpc_glue(1662): Callback received: 2 (cb_id=0x67E0001 handle=2)
03-01 11:37:43.529: D/RPC(1662): written RPC packet size: [28]
03-01 11:37:43.529: D/RPC(1662): read RPC packet
03-01 11:37:43.529: D/RPC(1662): read RPC packet size: [272]
03-01 11:37:43.529: V/locapi_rpc_glue(1662): Callback received: 4 (cb_id=0x67E0001 handle=2)
03-01 11:37:43.529: D/RPC(1662): written RPC packet size: [28]
03-01 11:37:43.539: D/RPC(1662): read RPC packet
03-01 11:37:43.539: D/RPC(1662): read RPC packet size: [272]
03-01 11:37:43.539: V/locapi_rpc_glue(1662): Callback received: 4 (cb_id=0x67E0001 handle=2)
03-01 11:37:43.539: D/RPC(1662): written RPC packet size: [28]
03-01 11:37:43.539: D/RPC(1662): read RPC packet
03-01 11:37:43.539: D/RPC(1662): read RPC packet size: [272]
03-01 11:37:43.539: V/locapi_rpc_glue(1662): Callback received: 4 (cb_id=0x67E0001 handle=2)
03-01 11:37:43.539: D/RPC(1662): written RPC packet size: [28]
03-01 11:37:43.539: D/RPC(1662): read RPC packet
03-01 11:37:43.539: D/RPC(1662): read RPC packet size: [272]
03-01 11:37:43.539: V/locapi_rpc_glue(1662): Callback received: 4 (cb_id=0x67E0001 handle=2)
03-01 11:37:43.539: D/RPC(1662): written RPC packet size: [28]
03-01 11:37:43.559: D/lib_locapi(1662): loc_eng_report_sv: valid_mask = 0x30, num of sv = 0
03-01 11:37:43.559: D/GpsLocationProvider(1662): reportSvStatus
03-01 11:37:44.410: D/RPC(1662): read RPC packet
03-01 11:37:44.410: D/RPC(1662): read RPC packet size: [208]
03-01 11:37:44.410: V/locapi_rpc_glue(1662): Callback received: 1 (cb_id=0x67E0001 handle=2)
03-01 11:37:44.410: D/RPC(1662): written RPC packet size: [28]
03-01 11:37:44.410: D/lib_locapi(1662): loc_eng_report_position: valid mask = 0x61ed, sess status = 1
03-01 11:37:44.520: D/RPC(1662): read RPC packet
03-01 11:37:44.520: D/RPC(1662): read RPC packet size: [272]
03-01 11:37:44.520: V/locapi_rpc_glue(1662): Callback received: 4 (cb_id=0x67E0001 handle=2)
03-01 11:37:44.520: D/RPC(1662): written RPC packet size: [28]
03-01 11:37:44.520: D/RPC(1662): read RPC packet
03-01 11:37:44.520: D/RPC(1662): read RPC packet size: [272]
03-01 11:37:44.520: V/locapi_rpc_glue(1662): Callback received: 4 (cb_id=0x67E0001 handle=2)
03-01 11:37:44.520: D/RPC(1662): written RPC packet size: [28]
03-01 11:37:44.520: D/RPC(1662): read RPC packet
03-01 11:37:44.520: D/RPC(1662): read RPC packet size: [272]
03-01 11:37:44.520: V/locapi_rpc_glue(1662): Callback received: 4 (cb_id=0x67E0001 handle=2)
03-01 11:37:44.520: D/RPC(1662): written RPC packet size: [28]
```

Sample of logcat when location updates are requested:

```
I/SIMPLE APP(12524): Starting location services.
D/AK8975  ( 1544): Ignore M_Sensor: (y, p, r) = ( 293,    1,    2), Status = 2
D/GpsLocationProvider( 1662): [handleMessage] message :8
D/GpsLocationProvider( 1662): [handleMessage] ADD_LISTENER
D/GpsLocationProvider( 1662): addListener(com.seedlabs.simplelocationproject)
D/GpsLocationProvider( 1662): setMinTime 0
V/GpsLocationProvider( 1662): enableLocationTracking ++
D/GpsLocationProvider( 1662): [handleMessage] message :3
D/GpsLocationProvider( 1662): [handleMessage] ENABLE_TRACKING
D/GpsLocationProvider( 1662): startNavigating
D/GpsLocationProvider( 1662): HtcBuildFlag.HtcCIQFlag(FALSE)
V/LocationManagerService( 1662): requestLocationUpdates
V/LocationManagerService( 1662): requestLocationUpdatesLocked: updateProvidersLocked
D/LocationManagerService( 1662): [updateProvidersLocked]
V/LocationManagerService( 1662): requestLocationUpdates
V/LocationManagerService( 1662): requestLocationUpdatesLocked: updateProvidersLocked
D/LocationManagerService( 1662): [updateProvidersLocked]
V/LocationManagerService( 1662): requestLocationUpdates
V/LocationManagerService( 1662): requestLocationUpdatesLocked: updateProvidersLocked
D/LocationManagerService( 1662): [updateProvidersLocked]
D/lib_locapi( 1662): [GPS:] loc_eng_set_qos_time_out(standalone = 16000, agps = 16000)
V/GpsLocationProvider( 1662): set_agps_qos_time_out complete
D/GpsLocationProvider( 1662): GpsLocationProvider_set_position_mode
D/lib_locapi( 1662): [GPS:] loc_eng_set_position mode, client = 2, interval = 1000, mode = 0
D/lib_locapi( 1662): [GPS:] loc_eng_set_position mode: GPS_POSITION_MODE_STANDALONE
D/lib_locapi( 1662): [GPS:] loc_eng_set_position mode before IOCTL, interval=1000, mode =4 preferred_accuracy=50, qos_timeout_standalone=16000, recurrence_type=1
V/lib_locapi( 1662): loc_eng_ioctl called: client = 2, ioctl_type = 2
V/locapi_rpc_glue( 1662): loc_ioctl
D/RPC     ( 1662): written RPC packet size: [96]
```

Comment: Could you include some of the log output youre getting from your log.i stuff?

Comment: Done.  I think [updateProvidersLocked] raises the most alarms, but Google gave me nothing on first try.

Comment: By the way friends, I forgot to mention:  If I go into Google Maps, it gets my position in moments flat.  Other apps seem to have no problems getting a location either.

Comment: I have the same issue. Did any of the below help ? Did you find the answer ? Please update.

Comment: Sorry Siddharth, I never did solve this issue.  I needed this functionality for a map, so I ended up using the MyLocationOverlay object from the android maps libraries object instead.  No word yet on why the Thunderbolt doesn't like the LocationManager stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Try reusing this code in `onCreate()` function,

```
List<String> providers = mLocationManager.getAllProviders();
        for (int i = 0 ; i < providers.size(); i++){
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(providers.get(i), 1, 1, mLocationListener);
        }
```

Comment: Tried both *moving* and *copying* this into onCreate, but no luck.  onResume() is definitely getting called because the log statement appears as expected: "Starting location services."

Answer (score 0):

Are your testing this while walking around or while sitting at your dev machine with USB attached for logcat output? I suspect that 2.3.4 is being more strict about the second and third params to:

```
requestLocationUpdates(providers.get(i), 1, 1, mLocationListener)
```

Those params throttle the rate at which the hardware generates updates. What youre currently using says only give me updates if the location changes by more than a meter AND no more often than every second.

From the [Location Manager docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html)

> If minDistance is greater than 0, a location will only be broadcasted
>   if the device moves by minDistance meters. To obtain notifications as
>   frequently as possible, set both parameters to 0.

Try this to see if it makes a difference. If not, please post your logcat output for more ideas.

```
requestLocationUpdates(providers.get(i), 0, 0, mLocationListener)
```

Comment: Oh, I think I left those set to 1 by accident.  I changed to values to zero but it didn't fix the problem.  I posted some logs for you as well - wish I could post all the output, but I reached my character limit pretty quick.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue on my Android tablet, until I realized that I hadn't enabled Google location services.  As soon as I did that, onLocationChanged started giving me updates based on the WiFi network I was connected to.  See this [help document](https://support.google.com/coordinate/answer/2569281?hl=en) for how to enable it (Settings -> Location on most Android devices).